# Path.getNameCount returns 1 if even if Path.get("") is just an empty string

Tags: java-8

It really does not makes sense why the console output is a bit inconsistent for Path.getNameCount whenever Path.get("").getNameCount() returns 1 wherein I expect it to be 0, when I use Path.get("C:\").getNameCount() returns 0 -> this one works as expected. I read the javadoc, there not much of an intuitive info about what happen so I have to ask is this something that needs fixing in java se? or I am missing something?

From [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#getNameCount--):

> int getNameCount()
>   Returns the number of name elements in the path.
>   Returns:
>   the number of elements in the path, or 0 if this path only represents a root component

```
//omitted codes
print(Paths.get(""));
print(Paths.get("C:"));
print(Paths.get("C:\\"));
//omitted codes
public static void print(Path path) {
    System.out.println("~~~~~~~ " + path + " ~~~~~~~");
    System.out.println("getRoot : " + path.getRoot());
    System.out.println("getParent : " + path.getParent());
    System.out.println("getFileName : " + path.getFileName());
    int nameCount = path.getNameCount();
    System.out.println("getNameCount : " + nameCount);
    if (nameCount > 1) {
        IntStream.range(0,nameCount).forEach(x->{
            System.out.println("getName(" + x + ") : " + path.getName(x) + "\t");
        });
    }
}
//omitted codes
```

Console Output:

```
~~~~~~~  ~~~~~~~
getRoot : null
getParent : null
getFileName :
getNameCount : 1
~~~~~~~ C: ~~~~~~~
getRoot : C:
getParent : null
getFileName : null
getNameCount : 0
~~~~~~~ C:\ ~~~~~~~
getRoot : C:\
getParent : null
getFileName : null
getNameCount : 0
```

Comment: What does empty path even mean?

Comment: Javadoc says: " A Path is considered to be an empty path if it consists solely of one name element that is empty. Accessing a file using an empty path is equivalent to accessing the default directory of the file system" So that part is consistent with the API specification (You only get 0 for roots).

Comment: thanks @Thilo that makes sense now :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Thilo, I realized that Paths.get("") is equivalent to the default directory or the current directory and as per specification I wont get 0 from getNameCount but 1, so I ran some test

```
System.out.println("isAbsolute : " + path.isAbsolute());
System.out.println("toAbsolutePath : " + path.toAbsolutePath());
```

console output:

```
isAbsolute : false
toAbsolutePath : C:\Users\user\Documents\java\NIO
```

so there, that makes sense now.is was never an empty path after all, but ofcourse toAbsolutePath return new Path object and is not equal to the original Path("")